# How to resolve Flutter app crashes on Samsung devices after Android 13 update?

Tags: flutter

After the Android 13 update, there have been reports of Flutter apps crashing specifically on Samsung devices. Users have encountered issues where their apps abruptly close or become unresponsive, leading to a frustrating user experience. While the exact cause of this problem is yet to be determined, it is speculated that certain compatibility issues between the Flutter framework and Samsung's customized version of Android 13 may be contributing factors. Flutter app developers and Samsung are actively investigating the issue and working towards a resolution to ensure a smoother app experience for Samsung users.

i was running flutter app in my device its working fine on every device except samsung devices

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics)? It can help identify and/or report the error that is occurring, the device, and other data that may be important in determining exactly what is going on.